# calling stored procedure with linq

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, linq-to-sql

I am new to Linq server.
I have a stored procedure in my databse that retuens count number.

```
select COUNT(*) from tbl_WorkerUsers 
        where WorkerCode=@Wcode
```

when I run it directly in my database it returns 1.

```
    exec checkWorkerCodeAvailibility 100000312
```

but when I run it in c# code it always returns null.

```
WorkerDataContext Wkc = new WorkerDataContext();
        int? result = Wkc.checkWorkerCodeAvailibility(Int32.Parse(Wcode)).Single().Column1;
```

what's wrong?

Comment: Add a breakpoint at                                                Wkc.checkWorkerCodeAvailibility(Int32.Parse(Wcode)).Single().Column1; and check the value of Wcode variable also check the profiler, that might give you a clue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define your Stored Procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[checkWorkerCodeAvailibility] 
    @Wcode int = 0
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Result INT
    SELECT @Result = COUNT(*) FROM tbl_WorkerUsers WHERE WorkerCode=@Wcode
    RETURN @Result
END
```

You can then access this using the following code:

```
int result = db.checkWorkerCodeAvailibility(Int32.Parse(WCode));
```