# when i drag and drop a procedure in dbml it shows returntype as none

Tags: .net, c#-3.0

Any one please help 
I have written a stored pocedure like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[STP_SELECTED_BOX_NO_FOR_ADMIN] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @list VARCHAR(500)
    AS
    BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    DECLARE @pos int

    --create table to hold parsed values
    CREATE TABLE #list (val varchar(10))

    --add comma to end of list
    SET @list = @list + ','

    --loop through list
    WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @list) > 0
    BEGIN
        --get next comma position
        SET @pos = CHARINDEX(',', @list)

        --insert next value into table
        INSERT #list VALUES (LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@list, @pos - 1))))

        --delete inserted value from list
        SET @list = STUFF(@list, 1, @pos, '')
    END

    SELECT * FROM VIEW_BOX_NO_FOR_ADMIN
    WHERE HoBoxNo IN (select val from #list) 
    ORDER BY HoBoxNo asc


END
```

when i drag stored procedure to my dbml file it gives return type as int and returns 0 all time, but i want result set to be returned, and when i run procedure in sql server management studio it gives me correct results,

any one please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to return your result. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497672/calling-stored-procedure-with-linq/5498055#5498055) for a simple example.