# using between in a controller ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have got the code below to return data from a table in my database.

I have tried and not been successful using stored procedures so can anyone advice how I use between two dates to get the below code to work.

Thanks

```
Imports System.Data.Entity

    Public Class HomeController
        Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    Private db As New ArticlesDBContextNew
        Function Index() As ActionResult
        ViewData("Message") = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application."

        Dim Articles = From Title In db.ArticlesList Select Title
        Articles = Articles.Where(Function(s) s.PublishdateFrom > (Date.Now.Date) And s.PublishDateTo > (Date.Now.Date))
        Return View(db.ArticlesList.ToList())
        Return View(Articles)
            Return View()
        End Function

        Function About() As ActionResult
            ViewData("Message") = "Your app description page."

            Return View()
        End Function

        Function Contact() As ActionResult
            ViewData("Message") = "Your contact page."

            Return View()
        End Function
    End Class
```

Comment: Unless your queries are extremely complicated, why not use the benefits of EF and LINQ? Why give yourself two sets of code to maintain?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to call it (via LINQ) like any other function.   Here is a good SO question with example code. [calling stored procedure with linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497672/calling-stored-procedure-with-linq)